# Viewing the source code where something is defined within Juno for Julia-lang

Tags: julia, juno-ide

Is there any easy way (such as Ctrl+click on a type, function, etc) to redirect to the source code definition of a type, function, macro, ... in the Juno IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `@edit` or `@which` macros.

Ex: `@edit 2*2`

Comment: I could not get a handle of `@edit` in the Juno IDE, but `@which` works fine

Comment: @A.Yazdiha you should add an environment variable for `@edit`(e.g. `export JULIA_EDITOR=subl`). Another way is to use `@less`.